# Does morphia support $switch projection?

Tags: morphia

```
"$switch": {
                        branches: [
                            { case: { $eq: [{ "$toLower": "$priority" }, "revenue loss"] }, then: 1 },
                            { case: { $eq: [{ "$toLower": "$priority" }, "critical"] }, then: 2 },
                            { case: { $eq: [{ "$toLower": "$priority" }, "high"] }, then: 3 },
                            { case: { $eq: [{ "$toLower": "$priority" }, "medium"] }, then: 4 },
                            { case: { $eq: [{ "$toLower": "$priority" }, "low"] }, then: 5 },
                        ],
                        default: 999
                    }
```

Searched latest versions but looks like there is no support of $switch .

Answer (score 0):

It currently does not.  I'm in the process of merging in the changes I made to make Morphia use the `PojoCodec` infrastructure in the newer driver versions.  That'll be 2.0.  2.1 will focus on the aggregation API among other things.

Comment: The new 2.0.0-RC1 definitely [supports](https://morphia.dev/2.0.0-RC1/javadoc/dev/morphia/aggregation/experimental/expressions/ConditionalExpressions.html#switchExpression()) it.